# How is ILogger<T> resolved via DI?

Tags: asp.net-core

I see various libraries resolving `ILogger<T>` from DI. For example, see Identity's [`SignInManager`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/SignInManager.cs#L39) class.

Where is `ILogger<T>` registered with the DI container to make this possible?

All I have been able to find is a `ILoggerFactory` instance being registered in Hosting's [`WebHostBuilder`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dfe427d3b32478db198f356ee22507b50461060d/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L73) class. This makes sense to allow resolving `ILoggerFactory`, but not `ILogger<T>` from application code.

From the Logging [examples](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/samples/SampleApp/Program.cs#L17), in order to create an `ILogger`, you have have to explicitly call `factory.CreateLogger()`.

Comment: I think this might be the code you are looking for https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs Like, you I could use some clarification on whether we should use ILoggerFactory to create logger instances or should we just declare that we need an ILogger<Foo> in our constructors.

Comment: it seems that Logger<T> itself takes ILoggerFactory in its own constructor so it can create the actual logger of the type. https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.Logging/LoggerOfT.cs I think I'm going to try it in myc code in places where I'm currently depending on ILoggerFactory and explicitly creating my own logger.

Comment: Wow, how did I not see that? That's the missing piece I was looking for.

Comment: I'm finding that it works just fine and seems more simple to just declare a dependency on ILogger<Foo>. I have one case where I'm creating some child objects directly rather than using DI and in that case I still need ILoggerFactory so I can pass it into the child objects to let them create their own logger.

Comment: Makes sense. If you want to post your answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ILogger<> is registered here as Logger<>:
https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

Logger<> takes ILoggerFactory into its own constructor so it can create the actual logger of whatever type:
https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerOfT.cs

So it seems like it is more simple to take a constructor dependency on a ILogger than to take one on ILoggerFactory in order to create a logger manually. But there are scenarios where you may need an ILoggerFactory if you need to create multiple types of loggers or new up other objects that also need to create loggers.

Comment: Broken links in answer

Comment: I've fixed the links