# How does .NET Core DI determine unspecified generic parameter like ILogger?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-core, reflection

(This question on ILogger is resolved [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751437/how-is-iloggert-resolved-via-di). My question asks how the DI system accomplishes it)

I was curious how .NET Core `ILogger<MyClass>` could be resolved for any type of `MyClass`. I checked the source code and found this one:

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>)));
```

So I understand that, when I need `ILogger<MyClass>`, the DI will automatically create a `Logger<MyClass>`. My question is, from Reflection, how does it happen? I made this code to investigate:

```
        var t1 = typeof(IList<>);
        Console.WriteLine(t1.FullName); // System.Collections.Generic.IList`1
        Console.WriteLine(t1.IsGenericType); // True
        Console.WriteLine(t1.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name); // T
        Console.WriteLine(t1.GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName); // null

        var t2 = typeof(IList<int>);
        Console.WriteLine(t2.FullName); // System.Collections.Generic.IList`1...
        Console.WriteLine(t2.IsGenericType); // True
        Console.WriteLine(t2.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name); // Int32
        Console.WriteLine(t2.GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName); // System.Int32
```

Weirdly enough, `t1` still has valid `GetGenericArguments()` result with the type being T (and null `FullName`).  Is that how the DI implementation check if the input type is `Something<>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the property [`ContainsGenericParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.containsgenericparameters?view=netstandard-2.1). It should always be `true` for a type like `typeof(IList<>)` and `false` otherwise.

> Gets a value indicating whether the current Type object has type parameters that have not been replaced by specific types.

I can imagine the implementation of a DI is similar to this:

```
        var abstraction = typeof(IList<>);
        var impl = typeof(List<>);

        var genericServices = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
        if (abstraction.ContainsGenericParameters)
        {
            genericServices.Add(abstraction.GetGenericTypeDefinition(), impl);

            // Other services
        }
```

Request service:

```
        var request = typeof(IList<int>);
        if (request.IsGenericType)
        {
            var requestGenType = request.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

            foreach (var genericService in genericServices)
            {
                if (requestGenType == genericService.Key)
                {
                    var implType = genericService.Value;

                    // Construct the dependency base on the information of implType
                }
            }

            // Not found service
        }
```